# Displaying camera image in real time and drawing over it

Tags: camera, gui

I am trying to make a remote controlled drone with an RPI and a RPI camera module. For that I wold like to display in real time what the drone is seeing (via the camera), and draw a GUI over it to display some information like speed etc. Can anyone tell me a good way to do that?

Comment: it's called a HUD (head up display) ... research that ... don't restrict your research to the Raspberry Pi ... there may be good solutions in the Linux realm

Answer (score 1):

Take a quick look at the python module opencv: https://opencv.org/

It comes with recognition features, real time camera reading and functionality to draw on the camera output. I haven't yet used it to display huds, but i am sure that it could do most of your needs.
Here is a little example code on how to get camera output and drawing on it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Here I am using Video device 0, since it is the only one that i have connected to it.
    # When having multiple video sources, increment the number to the correct one.
    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while true:
        # read camera frame
        _, img = capture.read()
        
        # get frame dimensions
        # we only need "width" here
        # height = img.shape[0]
        width = img.shape[1]
        # channels = img.shape[2]

        # draw on the image
        # in this case, a widthx50px purple rectangle on the top
        cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (width, 50), color=(255,0,255), thickness=5)

        # display the image
        cv2.imshow("Camera Output", img)

        # stop program on 'q' button input
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

    # close all windows after completion
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

To learn more about opencv, [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html) is their documentation and [HERE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d4d/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_gui.html) is the part that might interest you the most.

I hope I could help!